# Cannot Resolve Symbol ArrayList on OncreateView (fragment)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, arraylist, cannot-find-symbol

I want to initialize a new array list in a Fragment (onCreateView), but it says (cannot resolve symbol) and I don't know why.

[image]

How to fix that? since it seems that some statements change in the `onCreateView` method.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have found the solution.

I just needed to add an `ArrayList` , before initializing.

```
ArrayList articlesList = new ArrayList<Articles>();
ListView listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
ArticlesAdapter adapter = new ArticlesAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.articles, articlesList);
```